# Iframes automatically refresh when interacting with form - Ionic2/Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2

I am making a simple messaging app that embeds multiple Spotify widgets using iframe. The url to the song is stored in firebase and needs to be encoded & sanitized before displaying. When I interact with the form all the widgets refresh. Is there a way to prevent this refresh? I believe it is an issue with fetching the sanitized URL using a function, but I do not know how to fix.

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, af: AngularFire, messageData: MessageProvider,
              public channelProvider: ChannelProvider, public spotifyProvider: SpotifyProvider, public authProvider: AuthProvider,
              public messageProvider: MessageProvider, public sanitizer: DomSanitizer, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.channel = navParams.data.channel || {$key: 1};
    this.items = af.database.list('/channels/' + this.channel.$key);
    this.items.subscribe(x => {
      this.content && this.content.scrollToBottom(0)
    });
    this.messageForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      message: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  encodeURI(uri) {
    let url = `https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=${encodeURIComponent(uri)}`;
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }
```

```
<ion-row *ngIf="item.detail?.spotifyUri" class="spotifyPlayer">
   <iframe [src]='encodeURI(item.detail.spotifyUri)' width="100%" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
</ion-row>
```

Comment: Maybe this is something qith change detection. Try to use changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush on your component: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html